# C++ restore stream fmtflags

Tags: c++

Is it a good practice to avoid modifying the fmtflags of a stream permanently?

For instance, the function I wrote does

`std::ios_base::fmtflags flags = std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::boolalpha);`

at the beginning and

`std::cout.setf(flags);`

right before the end.

Should I do this? Suppose multiple unrelated functions use the same stream and require different formatting options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems self-evident that leaving the stream in the state you found it (as pertains to formatting flags) is a decent thing to do in the general case.

Whether you should actually do it in your specific case entirely depends on what other components use the same stream and what their expectations are of it.